# Problem with reading NFC data from iPhone Suica App using Android 7.0 or newer

Tags: android, nfc, applepay

My project requires to use Android device to read transaction history data from [Suica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suica), not only from physical card, but also from the mobile devices those integrated with a card via certain application. For the later, an example is Suica app on iPhone, which connects to Apple Pay service [link](https://www.jreast.co.jp/appsuica/).

My approach is simply using Android NFC API for both cases. We believe both physical card and mobile device with the Suica application actually can be treated as NFC-F (Felica) tag. The Suica application effectively work in card-emulation mode, doesn't it ?

The problem is with Android devices with SDK version up to Android 6.0 (API level 23) there is almost no difference when reading data either from physical card or mobile device, but for Android devices with SDK version from Android 7.0 (API level 24), it can hardly detect the mobile device as NFC-F tag, therefore we basically fail to read data from it.

Perhaps there are some changes in the Android SDK causing this problem, but I have no idea what are they, or how can I find them. Can someone explain this to me ? I have already posted a similar [question](https://teratail.com/questions/165785) to the Teratail but no answer.

-------------Updated 2019/05/01-------------

Having a look at Android SDK source code, it turns out that from the very version of SDK Android 7.0, the HostNfcFService for CardEmulation is added. Possibly not a coincidence but I haven't been able to figure out yet. [Github link](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-24/tree/master/android/nfc)

```xml
<!-- Scan activity -->
<activity
    android:name="xxxx.ScanActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

    <!-- NFC TAG -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

```xml
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an emulated Suica should behave almost exactly like a physical one, and you should be able to access its balance and history (assuming that this is also possible with a real card; I don't know too much about Suica's access configurations).

Have you tried enabling [reader mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) in the Android NFC API?

This disables various functionalities (e.g. Android Beam, card emulation mode) on the reading device that might interfere with accessing emulated cards on the target device.